# Считать несколько строк с клавиатуры в переменную

Tags: c#

У меня есть прибор, который работает в режиме клавиатуры. Он делает какие-то измерения и передает их по bluetooth на ПК. Проблема заключаются в том, что передается несколько строк, а с помощью стандартной функции Console.ReadLine() происходит следующее:

1. Считывается первая строка
2. Завершается выполнение функции и оставшийся текст вводится просто в VS.

Пробовал еще Console.In.ReadToEnd(). Не помогает. Возможно поможет перехват потока ввода.

EDIT: Console.In.ReadToEnd() работает, если текст руками вводить. а там прибор сам выплевывает значения в две строки. поэтому не помогает использование Console.In.ReadToEnd()

Comment: а вам обязательно считывать из консоли?

Comment: Чтобы считать несколько строк, нужно вызвать ReadLine несколько раз, другого способа нет. ReadToEnd "не помогает", потому что устройство не отправляет символ конца потока.